# write and read file on web service (axis2 + tomcat 7)

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

I'm writing a service for Axis2 + Tomcat7.0 with Java for the application. I've chosen to write any information to xml file, the problem is where is the root of the service/application server?

I read the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104180/web-service-in-java-using-tomcat-axis2-where-is-the-root-of-the-application) but isn't response good.

How can I get an absolute path to the writable directory by the service?

Answer (score 0):

I would set an environment variable and then read the value of it by using System.getProperty().

I think the default file writing location is wherever you are when you start the server, at least that's what I found with JBoss one time. The easiest thing is to either set an environment variable in a server property file, or create a property file for your service to use to retrieve the location. I've done it both ways with JBoss in windows and unix.