# Load the resource in Java

Tags: java

A simple issue about `class.getResource("path")`. Are the path according the class location? Someone tell me to see the ClassLoader but I got no nothing. How can I get the file on the root (If can how to rearch everywhere except type the absolute path). Appreciate for any reply.

```
try
{
    image = ImageIO.read(Images.class.getResourceAsStream(imageName));
    BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g = img.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g.dispose();
    image = img;
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to load resource file in java app. What sun recommended is using `Class.getResource("resource_name")` or `Class.getResourceAsStream("resource_name")` then you will get URL and InputStream respectively. If resource_name is specified without `/`, it will be prepend with Class package. So resource file must be in same place[folder structure] as the Class. What I love to do is call `getResource()` with `/` and put resource file at the root of package.

```
this.getClass().getResource("/resource/buttons1.png")
```

or

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resource/TX_Jello2.ttf")
```

Comment: Your answer really kill my suspicion.I ever thought the "/" is just to the subfoler.Now I got it.

Answer (score 0):

In your case:

```
Images.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + fileName)
```

will return an `InputStream` for a `File` specified by `imageName` relative to the class root folder. So If your class is in a package `com.company` (folder would be com/company) the `imageName` file (if this is only a file name) would reside inside the same folder as the "com" folder.

Comment: It seems if the filepath include the "/" it will find  the root?

Comment: You're absolutely correct. Missed the `/`. Had the same problem very recently. Maybe take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511163/axis2-tomcat-web-service-working-directory